# Groupby and sum based on column Value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID  Date       Category  Parameter  Color
1a1 2020-03-02    1          1       Red
1a1 2020-03-02    1          2       Green 
1a1 2020-03-02    2          1       Red
1a1 2020-03-03    2          2       Green
1a1 2020-03-03    3          1       Red
1a1 2020-03-03    3          2       Green   
1a2 2020-03-02    1          1       Red
1a2 2020-03-02
1a2 2020-03-02
```

And for a given Date, I want to know how many categories and parameters *PER ID* were flagged as red, so it would become something like this:

```
ID  Date       Category  Parameter  Color   count_red_category   count_red_parameter
1a1 2020-03-02    1          1       Red          1                     1
1a1 2020-03-02    1          2       Green        1                     1
1a1 2020-03-02    1          2       Red          1                     2
1a1 2020-03-02    2          1       Red          2                     2
1a1 2020-03-03    2          2       Green        0                     0
1a1 2020-03-03    3          1       Red          1                     1
1a1 2020-03-03    3          2       Green        1                     1   
1a2 2020-03-02    1          1       Red          1                     1
1a2 2020-03-02    1          1       Red          1                     1
```

Basically:

- At each datetime, a category and parameter are flagged as red/green.
- Each category can have multiple parameters
- For each datetime, I want the number of distinct categories up to that time (how many different categories for that ID, date flagged as Red)
- The same for parameter

Any idea what would be the best approach to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding, but first, you just care about the red values:

```
 tmpdf = df[df.Color=="Red"]
```

Then, you want to group by Id, date, and find the number of distinct categories:

```
 tmpdf.groupby(['ID', 'Date']).Category.nunique()
```

Of course, you can combine the two lines:

```
 newdf=df[df.Color=="Red"].groupby(['ID', 'Date']).Category.nunique()
```

If you want to keep dates/ids with no reds (give them 0), then:

```
finaldf=newdf.set_index(df.groupby(['ID','Date']).Category.count().index).fillna(value=0).
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I thought about this solution but I want to keep dates that have 0 categories/parameters flagged as non-red

Comment: @LuísCosta I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @LuísCosta you are saying you want to keep them in the list, for the dates and IDs?